# iPhone webdriver not locating element using CSS selector

Tags: iphone, webdriver

iPhone webdriver is not able to locate DOM elements using CSS selectors. I'm running the test on iPad simulator. In news.yahoo.com, trying to select an element using `findElement(By.cssSelector())`.

None of the below works. I can locate the element by `id` and `xpath` but css selector doesn't work. Getting no such element exception. Is this is a known issue? Any pointer would be helpful. Thanks!

```
findElementByCssSelector("mediamostpopular")

or
findElement(By.cssSelector("mediamostpopular"))
or
executeScript("document.querySelector('#mediamostpopular');"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Given Information I am able to see the ID #mediamostpopular.

In Selenium We can find the element given below as follows.

driver.findElement(By.id("mediamostpopular")).